# CMD exclude current folder path from string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can i replace current folder name in string?

I have this path: `tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll`

My bat file places in `D:/Make/apply.bat`

When i try to create folder from path above im getting current folder name in path.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%P in (tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll) do (
if not exist "folder%%~pP" md "folder%%~pP"
)
```

it makes path `D:/Make/Make/tld_Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll`, but i need `D:/Make/tld_Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll`

How to do that?

If i change string to `C:/tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll` everything is ok, but it's not nice..

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

**listA:**
`x:/tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
x:/tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll
x:/tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll
x:/tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript.dll`

**listB:**
`tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll
tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll
tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript.dll`

Comment: 1. The code now *reads the file contents* of `tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll` which is weird. 2. what is the real value of `folder` in `if not exist "folder%%~pP" md "folder%%~pP"`?

Comment: folder `tld_Data` is located near bat file
`D:/Make/tld_Data/Managed/`
But when i try to create it from cmd it append all folder names  as parent folder starting from root.
to be exact i need to create folder in current folder from this string `tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll` without filename and extension.

Comment: What is `list.bin` and how do you use it in the batch file?

Comment: listA.bin and listB.bin are text files with filepathes
listB is the same as listA but with `X:/` preffix (because of my problem)
i read listA line by line to match two folders recursively, and listB to create dir structure using this loop
`for /f "tokens=*" %%P in (listB.bin) do (
if not exist %patchfolder%%%~pP md %patchfolder%%%~pP
)`
so now i need to use two lists, besause when i try to create folders (with loop above) without imitating root folder path X:/ it creates wrong structure

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really anderstand your problem.

But give this a try :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%P in (listb.bin) do (
echo if not exist "%%~dpnxP" md "%%~dpnxP"
)
```

Remove the echo if the output is OK

Comment: Not exactly what i need.
Now it's `F:\tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll`
If i remove `dp` and add `path` it would be `\path\tld_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll`
But i wanna get this `path\tld_Data\Managed`